# Update Markers on Map from Searchresult using Leaflet, Search-Source and Meteor

Tags: meteor, leaflet

I want to update markers on a map. I'm using meteorhacks:search-source package for searching. It works.

At the moment the markers are set by observing the collection like:

```
collection.find({}).observe({
```

Now I want to 'observe' the search result. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `observe` of cursor

```
cursor = collection.find({})
cursor.observe(function() { ... })
```

Or you can put your `collection.find()` in a template helper, meteor will create to observer to watch the changes of database and update the related view template